# TortoiseSVN revert to previous revision without working copy

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, revert, working-copy

I committed a bunch of changes to the wrong branch. I used the Switch command to switch my working copy to the proper branch, and I merged/committed the changes from the other branch. Now I want to revert my changes from the wrong branch, but I would like to save the hassle of Switching or Checking Out a full copy of the branch.

Is there a way to revert to a previous revision directly in the repo without creating an intermediate working copy? There haven't been any other commits to the branch after my changes, so I don't need to reverse-merge my changes out, I only need to roll back to a previous revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Subversion `copy`, `move`, `delete`, and `mkdir` commands can work off of a URL instead of a working copy. Unfortunately for you, `svn merge` only works off of working copies.

This makes sense. When I use the other four commands, there is no doubt what my results will be. However, the `merge` command modifies individual files, and I really need to verify the changes made before I do my commit.

Comment: According to the [TortoiseSVN docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html), reverting revisions uses merging behind the scenes, so it follows that reverting requires a working copy. Thanks.